# Audio Chat using socketio

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, chat, audio-streaming

I am new in nodejs.
 I am working on voice chat application , in the application client can speak and his sound will broadcasted (using nodejs server) to other clients , I used socketio to send sound from microphone to server, but I did not know how receiver sound in client, Can any one help me?

Client code for send voice (I do not know if this true way to send voice from microphone):

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
navigator.getUserMedia( {audio:true}, gotStream , onError ); 
   function gotStream(stream) 
   {
                var context;
                if (window.AudioContext) {
                    context = new AudioContext();
                } else {
                    context = new webkitAudioContext();
                }
              var  mediastream = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
                var bufferSize = 2048;
                var myscriptnode = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);
                myscriptnode.onaudioprocess = function (event) {
                    var recordedData = event.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
                    socket.emit('broadcast', recordedData);
                };

                mediastream.connect(myscriptnode);
                myscriptnode.connect(context.destination);

      }


      function onError()
       {

       }
```

Server code for receiver from client:

```
socket.on('broadcast', function(data){
        socket.emit('broadcast', data);
    });
```

Client code to recive sound:

```
  socket.on('broadcast', function(data){
      // I do not know what I must do here      
    });
```

Comment: First issue : Navigator.getUserMedia() - Deprecated This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time.